# delete code deleting all instances of one primary key in the database instead of one record in the form

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

I have a link entity in my database.

I am using Oracle 10g to create forms. I have created a form where the link entity has three fields

- STUD_ID which is student id (PK)
- C_ID which is the class id (PK)
- SC_YEAR which the year the student takes the class

I have implemented a form to assign classes to particular students. The
update, insert and search functions work fine but when I try to delete, it deletes all instances of the C_ID for every student that takes this class.

It should delete that one particular instance of the class assigned to the particular student.

I am new to this so I am trying to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This my code

```
    PROCEDURE DISPLAY_DELETE_ALERT IS NUM NUMBER;
BEGIN

  NUM := SHOW_ALERT('DELETE_ALERT');

  IF NUM = ALERT_BUTTON1 THEN

    DELETE FROM STUDENT_CLASS
    WHERE :STUDENT_CLASS.C_ID= STUDENT_CLASS.C_ID AND
    STUDENT_CLASS.STUD_ID= STUDENT_CLASS.STUD_ID;
    COMMIT;

    NUM := SHOW_ALERT('CONFIRM_ALERT');


  END IF;

  EXECUTE_QUERY;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code:

```
STUDENT_CLASS.STUD_ID= STUDENT_CLASS.C_ID
```

This says where `STUD_ID = C_ID` -- don't think that is what you want?  Maybe you want this?

```
:STUDENT_CLASS.STUD_ID= STUDENT_CLASS.STUD_ID
```

Also, does it make send to name your variables the same as your table.  This might be making it more confusing to you.

Comment: sorry my apologies i was fiddling with the code in desperation . i edited the code in my question to what you suggest because that was my original code but it still deletes all the instances of C_ID

Comment: please post a question with code that reflects the actual question

Comment: i figured it out i was missing a second colon before the second line. Your answer helped me figure it out. Thank you

Comment: @IidsSunglassesTnt - if my answer helped you should upvote the answer and mark it as correct.